# Image with transparent background start to have one in android studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, background, transparent

I'm trying to add an image with transparent background in android studio to a new empty project, but when I add it, it keeps giving me the transparent background as a background

[Here's the image I'm trying to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuBc0.jpg)

[Here's what keeps happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XemLa.png)

I tried many other images but the same thing keeps happening and I looked online but all I found was how to make the image itself transparent or semi-transparent but not the background

Here's the code in the xml file if it helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ahmad.connectfour.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/eye"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the java file is not edited at all

Answer (score 0):

use this eye icon:

[image]

visit the link for more icons: https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=check_circle_outline&style=baseline

Comment: that worked for the eye but if I want to add another image and I didn't find it the material.io what should I do?